SSDT Installation issue on VS2022
I am facing an issue with SSDT. I need the tool for my SSIS project. I have followed the steps mentioned in the following link.
As I launch VS Installer I see this.

To me it means SSDT is already installed. However when I click on the start menu, I do not see SSDT. I see this

What is going wrong? I am on Windows 11.

You need to download and install the SSIS Extension (separate EXE/MSI and requires admin rights to install). SSIS isn't part of SSDT anymore - same for SSRS and SSAS, though those are both VSIX packages.
